# What does “no data” in search appearance of google webmaster tool/search console mean?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, ranking

Search appearance section has no data to show. It has been months since some of the pages and posts of my website got indexed to google. But I see no data in search appearance. Does this mean that none of my pages or posts appear in SERP. If yes what can be done?
Additional information: Around 70 pages which are all deleted were crawled and passed indexing earlier which still appears in pages report.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The search console display no detailed information on pages and keywords when it has been created and instanciated too recently.
If it's not your case, it only seems that google doesn't have enough individual data to display. 116 impressions is not significative enough.

Also the search appearance tab, google will only count the custom displays like AMP, FAQ and so on, not the standard SERP features.
So if you didn't implement any rich display feature, you won't be able to see anything here.